# Inject non-singleton service into non-singleton service in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

What would be the way to go if I wanted to inject a non-singleton service into another non-singleton service in Angular?

Let's say I have a `ComponentA` which uses a `ServiceA` like this

```
@component({
  selector: "componentA",
  providers: [ServiceA]
})
export class ComponentA {
  constructor(private serviceA: ServiceA) {}
}
```

and now, `ServiceA` also depends on `ServiceB`, so I need to inject it

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
   constructor(private serviceB: ServiceB) {}
}
```

How/where would I declare my `ServiceB`? In the module? In that case would that be a singleton?

If I add it to the providers in `ComponentA` it works fine, but then I need to know in `ComponentA` that `ServiceA` depends on `ServiceB`, which doesn't seem fine to me.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a very valid question ... so it would be nice to know why people are voting it down. (I am very much in favor of banning the down vote!)

Comment: Well, why do you not want to have a singleton service in the first place?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner a stateful service maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, unless you have the `providedIn` options in the `@Injectable()`, Angular will not treat the service as a singleton. You can refer to the docs for details on how that works: https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#providedin

The issue that you will run into, is that if you simply do:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceB {
   constructor() {}
}
```

It will throw an error when trying to inject ServiceB into ServiceA because it has no provider. Now normally, to resolve this, you would add `{ providedIn: 'root' }` to ServiceB's `@Injectable()`. This will create service B as an application-wide singleton service.

When you use `@Component( { providers: [] } )` that will create an instance *just for that component*. But you can't do that for a service.

You may ask, why doesn't `@Injectable()` have a `providers` option like `@Component()` does? The Angular team doesn't want to do this for a number of reasons, see this github issue for more info https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622

**TLDR:**

To provide you with something to solve this problem, you can keep it simple and avoid using Angular's DI altogether if you want control over what instances you use, you can just do it yourself:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
   constructor(private serviceB: ServiceB = new ServiceB()) {}
}
```

or

- use Angular's DI with `@NgModule()` and/or `@Component()` `providers` arrays,
- `@Injectable( { providedIn: <something> } )` (https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#providedin)

Edit: as suggested by @minigeek, using `providedIn` you can use `any` to make  each lazy module get it's own instance of the service.

Comment: not anymore with Angular 11. providedin : any created instance per moduke

Comment: Right, but that is still one service per (lazy) module. That might answer the question, hence why included the link to the providedIn options.

Comment: Got ya!.. yeah u can add that in answer

Answer (score -1):

Services are always singletons in the scope of where they're provided so if you provide B in a module, it'll be the same singleton to everyone using that module. I think you need to use Injector directly in service A to do it your way.

See https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable